# Warning: The optional WSDL extension element 'body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not handled

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, wsdl

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, .Net4, Silverlight(4.0.50826.0).

I created a WCF service and I`m trying to create a proxy with SlSvcUtil like:

```
SlSvcUtil.exe /serializer:DataContractSerializer http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?wsdl /out:C:\Projets\Client\dService.cs /config:C:\Projets\Client\ServiceReferences.ClientConfig
```

When I add some methods with customer type and also they have some attributes I got this msg:

> Warning: The optional WSDL extension element 'body' from namespace 
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not handled.
>
> XPath:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@
>   name='BasicHttpBinding_IService']/wsdl:operation[@name='GetDefinitionsHavingFre']/wsdl:output

If I ignore the warning and I try to use the class I get a NullException error when I call any method.

If I change the option `/Serializer:XmlSerializer` or any other option Its possible create the proxy correctly but I get a lot of null references in the visual studio, so Its necessary to add the correct .dll.

If I add: `System.ServiceModel` from Silverlight   -the xmlserializerformatattribute doesn't exist `System.ServiceModel`  from .NET          -the ChannelBase doesn't exist

If I didn't use the customer method my service works fine, so my question is has silverlight some limit when use customer types or methods with attributes ?

Someone has some clue what could be done to solve this ?

Thanks,

WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <wsdl:definitions name="TestService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
- <wsdl:types>
- <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd10" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataCompany.Data.Faults" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataCompany.Data.PortalModel" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd4" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd5" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd6" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataCompany.Data.Components" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd7" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd8" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataCompany.Data" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server?xsd=xsd9" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataCompany.Data.LocalizationManagement" /> 
  </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_StatusService_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:StatusService" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_StatusService_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:StatusServiceResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_getData_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getData" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_getData_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getDataResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_getTime_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getTime" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_getTime_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getTimeResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_getText_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getText" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_getText_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getTextResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_SaveEntity_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SaveEntity" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_SaveEntity_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SaveEntityResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ITestService_SaveEntity_DatabaseFaultFault_FaultMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="detail" element="q1:DatabaseFault" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataCompany.Data.Faults" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:portType name="ITestService">
- <wsdl:operation name="StatusService">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/StatusService" message="tns:ITestService_StatusService_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/StatusServiceResponse" message="tns:ITestService_StatusService_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="getData">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/getData" message="tns:ITestService_getData_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/getDataResponse" message="tns:ITestService_getData_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="getTime">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/getTime" message="tns:ITestService_getTime_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/getTimeResponse" message="tns:ITestService_getTime_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="getText">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/getText" message="tns:ITestService_getText_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/getTextResponse" message="tns:ITestService_getText_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="SaveEntity">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/SaveEntity" message="tns:ITestService_SaveEntity_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/SaveEntityResponse" message="tns:ITestService_SaveEntity_OutputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:fault wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/SaveEntityDatabaseFaultFault" name="DatabaseFaultFault" message="tns:ITestService_SaveEntity_DatabaseFaultFault_FaultMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
- <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" type="tns:ITestService">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
- <wsdl:operation name="StatusService">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/StatusService" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="getData">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/getData" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="getTime">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/getTime" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="getText">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/getText" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="SaveEntity">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ITestService/SaveEntity" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
- <wsdl:fault name="DatabaseFaultFault">
  <soap:fault name="DatabaseFaultFault" use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:fault>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
- <wsdl:service name="TestService">
- <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ITestService">
  <soap:address location="http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

---

Comment: If it is possible to add the WSDL from the service to your question then you may get some responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found the problem.

After creating the proxy with `SlSvcUtil` and adding the .cs in my project in Visual Studio I got this error:

> The type or namespace name 'XmlSerializerFormatAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

First of all I tried change the `System.Service.Model` from the Silverlight version to the .Net version, but I got other errors.

So I found somewhere that was necessary, use `/serializer:DataContractSerializer` in the `SlSvcUtil`; after that this error was solved.  However I got a WSDL warning when the proxy is generated.

#### SOLUTION

1. I created the proxy using the following command:

   ```
   SlSvcUtil.exe http://192.128.09.26:8080/Server /out:C:\Projets\Client\dService.cs /config:C:\Projets\Client\ServiceReferences.ClientConfig
   ```

   Then the I got this error in Visual Studio:

   > The type or namespace name 'XmlSerializerFormatAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2. I added the following dll:

   - System.Xml.Serialization.dll   - (Runtime Version v2.0.50727)

#### Conclusion

Visual Studio wasn't able to find the reference inside the ServiceModel.dll and the ServiceModel was there so I never thought to add another .dll because the correct dll was already added.

Just yesterday I tried add the System.Xml.Serialization.dll and now everthing works fine.