# Error while adding service reference to C# Console App

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, console-application, service-reference

I built a C# windows app that uses a web service and it is working fine.
I am building a C# Console app which will be used in the scheduler to automate the process and run at night.
I am having issues adding the same service reference to the console app.
I get an error while trying to add the service reference. I do not understand why I get this error on the console app but not the windows form app.

I get the below error on adding the service reference. Any ideas or help appreciated.

> Cannot import wsdl:port\r\nDetail: \r\nXPath to Error Source:
> //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='https://www.cbh.com/']/wsdl:service[@name='ExportService']/wsdl:port[@name='ExportServiceHttpPost']
> Cannot import wsdl:binding\r\nDetail: The required WSDL extension
> element 'binding' from namespace
> 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.\r\nXPath to
> Error Source:
> //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='https://www.cbh.com/']/wsdl:binding[@name='ExportServiceHttpPost']
> Cannot import wsdl:port\r\nDetail: \r\nXPath to Error Source:
> //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='https://www.cbh.com/']/wsdl:service[@name='ExportService']/wsdl:port[@name='ExportServiceHttpGet']
> Cannot import wsdl:binding\r\nDetail: The required WSDL extension
> element 'binding' from namespace
> 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.\r\nXPath to
> Error Source:
> //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='https://www.cbh.com/']/wsdl:binding[@name='ExportServiceHttpGet']

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, the wsdl does not seem to match the schema reference of the data contract serializer. You may refer to [the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553618/warning-the-optional-wsdl-extension-element-body-from-namespace-http-schem) for more help.